# How to fix "SyntaxError: Failed to execute 'evaluate' on 'Document':"?

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium-chromedriver

I am trying to copy the xpath of an element, but it keeps saying that the xpath is incorrect

Here is the code I have done:

```py
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("https://www.bol.com/nl/v/bananago-nl/1067588/")
x = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id=js_overview']/ul/li[2]/div/div[2]/p/text()[2]")
print(x)
```

The element I am trying to copy is the text that says "12 beoordelingen". Let me know if you need any more information

Comment: please add complete error traceback

Comment: Looks like you do have a syntax error in your xpath: a superfluous `'` before the close square bracket

Comment: @DanielRoseman Now I am getting ```selenium.common.exceptions.InvalidSelectorException: Message: invalid selector: The result of the xpath expression "//*[@id='js_overview']/ul/li[2]/div/div[2]/p/text()[2]" is: [object Text]. It should be an element.```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the initial single quote in 'js_overview'.

Comment: Now I am getting ```selenium.common.exceptions.InvalidSelectorException: Message: invalid selector: The result of the xpath expression "//*[@id='js_overview']/ul/li[2]/div/div[2]/p/text()[2]" is: [object Text]. It should be an element.```

Comment: It says "It should be an element" so you need to take out "text()[2]" and use the "x.text" to get the text.

Answer (score 0):

To get the Text `12 beoordelingen` you need to induce `WebDriverWait` and `element_to_be_clickable()` to get the element and then

Induce JavaScripts Exceutor `execute_script()` and get the `lastChild`  `textContent` .

Try below code.

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("https://www.bol.com/nl/v/bananago-nl/1067588/")
element=WebDriverWait(driver,20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,"//div[@id='js_overview']//div[@class='media__body']/p")))
print(driver.execute_script('return arguments[0].lastChild.textContent;', element))
```